# rule that matches file containing a pattern

Tags: makefile

How do I create a rule that matches any file that contains `foo`, like `a/foo.h` or `foo.c`? Double `%` sign doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOOS := $(shell find . -name "*foo*")

$(FOOS):
    @echo do something with $@
```

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: Well, you did say any *file*.